# Mailer wont work correctly

Tags: php, html, email, post, mailer

I'm trying to use this mailer and have it redirect to a success/fail page depending on the fields a user enters. It works and sends the mail and also redirects to a success page when all the fields are entered, but when nothing is entered it just goes to a blank page but still sends the mail?

How could I make this work as intended? Ideally I would like it to just direct to the same page and show a success or error message within the page but I don't know how to do it.

My code for my mailer is below:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$features = $_POST['features'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$timeline = $_POST['timeline'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$additional = $_POST['additional'];

$to = "hello@phnx-creative.co";
$subject = "Project Req: $company";
$body = "Name: $name \n\n Company Name: $company \n\n Email: $email \n\n Phone Number: $phone \n\n Website: $website \n\n Features: $features \n\n Budget: $budget \n\n Timeline: $timeline \n\n Content: $content \n\n Additional Info: $additional";
$from = $email;

if(!empty($_POST['name']) || !empty($_POST['email']) || !empty($_POST['phone']) || !empty($_POST['features']) || !empty($_POST['budget']) || !empty($_POST['timeline']) || !empty($_POST['content'])){ 

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    header("Location: success.php");
} else {
    header("Location: error.php");}
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you executing this script on a website or on your localhost?

Answer (score 0):

You don;'t appear to have $headers set. That may be the issue, set it up so that it sends it with $headers

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement where you check that you received everything through `POST` , you should use the "and" comparator `&&` and not the "or" comparator `||`. In your case, the condition will be true if only one of the `POST` variable is not empty - unless this is what you want?

You should also check the content of the `POST` variables **before** assigning their value to your variables at the top. You could do something like suggested by Tibbers.